# drupal 7 response with two sets of html, a normal, followed by an in-maintenance with an error message

Tags: drupal-7

I have a weird problem on my localhost devop preventing me from updating drupal.
**problem**
Every page is served with two sets of html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" ...>
   <body class="html front ...">
      ...
   </body>
</html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <body class="maintenance-page in-maintenance no-sidebars fluid-width">
       ...
   </body>
</html>
```

- where the second page is a rendering of the maintenance page

** what I am looking for**
as i spend like 8 hours debugging this, I am at my wits end, and looking for an other perspectives or suggestions

**context**

- the problem is not theme related becaus it does this for every theme
- the weird thing is that this local version is an exact copy (code, database, php version, .htacces) of the online production version that does not have this problem
- the only difference is an  error i get on my local devop

`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DateObject::limitGranularity() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sontheing/xdev_en_rli_nl/sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date.module on line 255 in DateObject->limitGranularity()`

- Trying to temporarily resolve this error, to see if this is the cause of my weird double html, sends me down a rabbithole patching various date modules.... And I don understand how a type error could have this weird double html rendering result...
- the only other occurence of this problem with someone else i could find here
  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269926/maintenance-page-being-rendered-as-an-entire-page-load-after-the-main-page-load

**Question**
Does this problem ring a bell for someone.
Has anybody seen this before?

[how it looks in garland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eFVM.png)

Comment: Did you try to clear all (Including opcode) cache ? The `mainteance_mode` is stored in the 'variable' table in db, what is its value ? Try to disable/enable the `devel` module and see if it changes anything. Checks your logs. For debugging, you can hook into the preprocessing phase of the 'maintenance_page' theme and print a backtrace from there : in a module, create a function `<module_name>_preprocess_maintenance_page()` and let it call `ddebug_backtrace()`.

Comment: @EricLavault
thanx for your suggestions --
tried disabling devel (and also all other modules) -- 
the maitenance_mode in variable is correct (0 or one, tried it all) -- 
logs are unclear, only the aformentioned error  -- 
will try the backtrace suggestion

Comment: the backtrace simply gives me the render array for the maintenance page

The problem is that i do not understand whay this extra maintenace page with the eroor message is triggerend en added to the response....

Comment: The backtrace is meant to let you know how the executed code got into the function where you generate it, look at the call stack (what called the function that called the function ... that called `theme('maintenance_page')`). Post the formatted backtrace output. First `ddebug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS)` to remove the function/method arguments and focus on the call stack.

Comment: yeh, i know, the backtrace is normal for the page, but then there is the other backtrace as if there is a new call to the maintenance page but in the admin theme. So its like an ghost calling that second page and drupal just rendering them together..... (I am suspecting black magick at this moment....)

Comment: "_the backtrace is normal for the page_" what does it mean ? Post the backtrace output in a readable format if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

- problem 1 -
  I havent a clue howcome drupal rendered two html pages in the same response, but found the culprit in my case
- problem 2 -
  I traced the problem back to the cron and apache solr, which ultimately crashed on a specific node.
  Opening that node it also crashed. (Noone ever found that problem because these nodes are rarely viewed, cuase they are mainly historic)
  so that was the reason the cron crashed
  The error stemming from the date field
- reason 2 -
  The reason for the page crashing is that drupal tried to render a long text field via the date formatter. Which is weird because i use the same field in other content types and there it is rendered as a text field.
- solution 2 -
  So, i have not yet discovered why drupal thought that these instances of this text field where date fields, but the solution here was to save the contents of the text fields (I could open the nodes in the editor) then remove the text field from the contenttype, then add a new text field and restore the contents for each node....
- followup 2 -
  If i can find the reason why drupal thought a text field was a date field I will report that in this thread